# Does AVR subtraction of equal numbers set the SREG C-flag?

Tags: assembly, avr, integer-arithmetic

Short background: 
The BRLO (Branch if Lower) instruction is stated to 
1. ... perform the branch if the C-flag == 1;
2. ... perform the branch if Rd < Rr (from a CP instruction)

My question:
I will use 4-bit numbers for demonstration. Suppose that Rd = Rs = 3 = 0011. From point 2 above, the branch should NOT happen. The CP instruction performs Rd - Rr. IF we use two's complement for the subtraction, we have
0011 - 0011 = 0011 + 1100 + 0001 = 0000 
WITH a C-flag = 1. Point 1 above therefore contradicts point 2.

Assuming that I am wrong: where did I mess up?

Thanks

Comment: `x-x` does **not** set `CF` since there is no overflow. Yes, the addition would set it, and there are some architectures where `CF` meaning is indeed reversed for subtraction. AVR is not one of them. See also the instruction set reference which says _"[CF] Set if the absolute value of the contents of Rr is larger than the absolute value of Rd; cleared otherwise."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, operations which give the same result are not always equivalent operations. So, your assumption, that  0011 - 0011 = 0011 + 1100 + 0001 and will have the same carry flag value - is wrong

Although A + (~B + 1) gives you the same result as A - B it is not the same, and will not update the flags in the same way.

In fact, you forgot one thing. In your example:

`0011 + 1100 + 0001 = 0000` - is wrong. Because 0011 + 1100 + 0001 = ***1**0000*

You forget that A + (~B + 1) equals to A - B *only* when considering the two's complement **overflow**.

Now you can see the carry flag will be very opposite in the both operations. In fact, A + ~B + 1 will have the overflow (in either first or second addition) then and only then, when A - B have no borrow (underflow).

When performing addition C flag means the overflow has happened, i.e. one should be carried out from at left of the leftmost bit.

I.e. if you are adding:

```
  0110
+ 1101
  ----
 10011
  ^^^^ the result
 ^ the carry flag
```

That means, if you conduct addition on a longer number, composed of several registers, you have to add one to the higher part. E.g.

```
 add r16, r18 // adds r18 to r16, C flag is set only when overflow happened
 adc r17, r19 // adds r19 to r18, and add one if C flag is set. updates the C flag by the overflow again
 // in result r17:r16 = r17:r16 + r19:r18
```

When doing subtraction, C flag means the borrow happened from the left of the leftmost bit, and higher part of the number, therefore, should be decreased by one

```
 *  *  - borrow positions
  0110
- 1101
  ----
  0001
 ^ carry flag is set when borrowed at left from the leftmost positions.
```

In assembler you have the `sbc` instructions, which makes the subtraction as the `sub` instruction, but decreases result by one if carry flag is set

```
 sub r16, r18 // subtracts r18 from r16, C flag is set only when underflow happened
 sbc r17, r19 // subtracts r19 from r18, and subtracts one more if C flag is set. updates the C flag by the underflow again
 // in result r17:r16 = r17:r16 - r19:r18
```

So, answering your question: when you subtract the number from itself, the value of carry flag is cleared, because no underflow has happened.

AVR architecture has a simple branching mechanics. It has 8 flags bit and every branch instruction makes branch depending on value of only one bit from those.

So, `BRLO` and `BRCS` both are mnemonics for the same machine code, which makes branch if carry flag is set. Carry flag is set only when you subtract a higher unsigned value from a lower one.

If you want to make signed comparison, then you have to use the `BRLT` instruction, which looks at the `S` flag, which equals to the exclusive OR of flags `N` and `V`. `N` flag is set when operation result is a negative signed number (higher bit is set). `V` flag means the signed overflow has happened. Their exclusive or combination says when a greater signed number was subtracted from a lesser one.